# reference request for finiteness theorem for $K_2$

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

Is there an algebraic proof of the finiteness theorem for $K_2$ of number fields available?
The Garland's [proof (1971)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970769) heavily relies on transcendental methods.